# Import not recognizing installed python package installed by pip, sys.path correct

Tags: path, pip, python-import, filepath, sys

I've installed the mortgage package using pip. The command prompt below shows where it's installed.

```
C:\Users\benja>pip show mortgage
Name: mortgage
Version: 1.0.5
Summary: Mortgage Calculator
Home-page: https://github.com/austinmcconnell/mortgage
Author: Austin McConnell
Author-email: austin.s.mcconnell@gmail.com
License: MIT license
Location: c:\users\benja\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

I'm able to run Python through the command prompt and successfully import/use the package, like so...

```
C:\Users\benja>py
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mortgage import Loan
>>> Loan(principal=250000, interest=.04, term=30)
<Loan principal=250000, interest=0.04, term=30>
```

This makes sense because the sys path points to the folder where the package is installed.

```
C:\Users\benja>py
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(sys.path)
['',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

**The issue:** I've created a module buysellcalculator.py that imports the mortgage package, simliar to what I did in the command prompt above. However, I get an error message when trying to run this module. What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\Users\benja\OneDrive\Documents\R\Real Estate\PyRM>buysellcalculator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benja\OneDrive\Documents\R\Real Estate\PyRM\buysellcalculator.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mortgage import Loan
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mortgage'
```

Comment: You made all your checks by running `py`, but run your script by executing it directly. Have you tried running it with `py buysellcalculator.py` to make sure the correct interpreter is used?

Comment: I tried this and got the same result. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mortgage'